# "Invalid or unsupported executable format" when using superGRUB2

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, encryption

I am currently using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a laptop without any other OSs. Recently, my laptop started booting into the GRUB command line (note: note grub rescue> but just grub>). I tried following the steps here: https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux , but got a little mixed up along the way. The second `ls` command (i.e. the one on the partition) doesn't return the expected output. Additionally, it shows two partitions, whereas I had maintained only a single partition. I suspect that this is because I encrypt my hard disk, which requires a passphrase unlock before I can boot the OS.

Therefore, I tried SuperGRUB2, mentioned at the bottom of the same page. However, despite following the instructions here: http://www.supergrubdisk.org/wizard-restore-grub-with-super-grub2-disk/ I am seeing the following output while trying to get into the "Super Grub2 Disk screen" (i.e. the screen that should show the "Detect any Operating System screen"):

```
Error 13: (http://grub4dos.chenall.net/e/13)
Invalid or unsupported executable format
Press any key to continue...
```

The URL mentioned in the error doesn't lead to an active page.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated. I have a lot of data saved on this laptop that I haven't backed up, and I've been in crisis mode for the past 3-4 hours!

Thank You

Comment: If it helps, I wanted to add that my laptop started booting into GRUB when it froze in the middle of installing new Generic Linux Headers from the Update Manager.

Comment: Also, I tried searching Google for the error message. I came across this: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2292617 but was unclear on the suggestion, since I am already using GRUB2.

Comment: Output from the Boot-Repair tool's BootInfo option, mentioned here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2292617&p=13346886#post13346886 -> http://paste.ubuntu.com/23926318/