# Mount encrypted laptop volume from bootable media?

Tags: mount, permissions, live-usb, encryption

This is a question related to a [previous question I had asked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879796/invalid-or-unsupported-executable-format-when-using-supergrub2) about fixing GRUB related issues with Ubuntu.

Essentially, while I can't boot into Ubuntu installation on the laptop itself, I thought I could:

1. Create a bootable pendrive with Ubuntu on it.
2. Try to mount the encrypted volume [from Nautilus, as mentioned in the question here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63594/mount-encrypted-volumes-from-command-line#)
3. Try to copy the data from my home directory.

However, on trying this, I get the following error message:

```
This location could not be displayed.
You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "sraje".
```

Any suggestions to get this to work would be tremendously helpful. As I mentioned in my original post, I have a lot of data saved on this laptop that I haven't backed up, and it's very important for me that I recover it!

Thank You

Comment: You did manage to mount the volume right ? Then it should be a matter of using "sudo" either for the "cp" command on the command line, or with Nautilus.

Comment: @albertj I tried what you mentioned. However, on doing a `sudo ls sraje` , instead of seeing my folders, all I can see are two files, one labelled `README.txt` and another called `Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop` . I'll try posting the output of the two files in a few minutes.

Comment: `README.txt` -> https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c10ab7232fc2991767c4aa1028bed08f ; `Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop` -> https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9e68154fab37a3e74888f78f290c6a9d

Comment: Good. So, that output shows that you are using home directory encryption with ecryptfs. You need to unlock that one as well. Try e.g. this, see comments : https://askubuntu.com/questions/36573/trying-to-mount-old-encrypted-home